# WebGL fade-out does not work for white color

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am trying to adapt a webgl code that generates firework explositions, where projectiles fade out from canvas by means of painting over with 0.1 alpha (as I understand it).
However, this technique somehow doesn't work for the explosition of `white` color.

You can see that `white` projectiles leave traces and never fully disappear, while other colors work fine (or maybe they also don't work, but I don't see the traces on black background).
Can somebody help me understand what is happening here?

```js
// from https://codepen.io/towc/pen/oBvYEL

var gl = c.getContext('webgl2', {preserveDrawingBuffer: true})
    , w = c.width = window.innerWidth
    , h = c.height = window.innerHeight

    , webgl = {}
    , opts = {
    projectileAlpha: .8,
    projectileLineWidth: 2,
    fireworkAngleSpan: .5,
    baseFireworkVel: 3,
    gravity: .02,
    xFriction: .995,
    baseShardVel: 1,
    addedShardVel: .2,
    fireworks: 1, // 1 firework for each 10x10 pixels,
    baseShardsParFirework: 10,
    addedShardsParFirework: 10,
    shardFireworkVelMultiplier: .3
}

// updated to use WebGL2 and GL ES 3.0
// pass full color instead of just hue
// remove moving projectile, keep only the explosion

webgl.vertexShaderSource = `#version 300 es
uniform int u_mode;
uniform vec2 u_res;
in vec4 a_data;
out vec4 v_color;

vec3 c2rgb(int color_int){
    int r = color_int >> 16;
    int g = color_int >> 8 & 0xff;
    int b = color_int & 0xff;
    return vec3(r/255, g/255, b/255);
}

void clear(){
    gl_Position = vec4( a_data.xy, 0, 1 );
    v_color = vec4( 0, 0, 0, a_data.w );
}
void draw(){
    gl_Position = vec4( vec2( 1, -1 ) * ( ( a_data.xy / u_res ) * 2. - 1. ), 0, 1 );
    v_color = vec4( 1, 1, 1, a_data.w );
}
void main(){
    if( u_mode == 0 )
        draw();
    else
        clear();
}
`;
webgl.fragmentShaderSource = `#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
in vec4 v_color;
out vec4 fragColor;

void main(){
    fragColor = v_color;
}
`;

webgl.vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(webgl.vertexShader, webgl.vertexShaderSource);
gl.compileShader(webgl.vertexShader);
if (!gl.getShaderParameter(webgl.vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS))
    console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(webgl.vertexShader));

webgl.fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(webgl.fragmentShader, webgl.fragmentShaderSource);
gl.compileShader(webgl.fragmentShader);
if (!gl.getShaderParameter(webgl.fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS))
    console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(webgl.fragmentShader));

webgl.shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(webgl.shaderProgram, webgl.vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(webgl.shaderProgram, webgl.fragmentShader);

gl.linkProgram(webgl.shaderProgram);
gl.useProgram(webgl.shaderProgram);

webgl.dataAttribLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(webgl.shaderProgram, 'a_data');
webgl.dataBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(webgl.dataAttribLoc);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, webgl.dataBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(webgl.dataAttribLoc, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

webgl.resUniformLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(webgl.shaderProgram, 'u_res');
webgl.modeUniformLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(webgl.shaderProgram, 'u_mode');

gl.viewport(0, 0, w, h);
gl.uniform2f(webgl.resUniformLoc, w, h);

gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
gl.enable(gl.BLEND);

gl.lineWidth(opts.projectileLineWidth);

webgl.data = [];

webgl.clear = function () {

    gl.uniform1i(webgl.modeUniformLoc, 1);
    let a = .1;
    webgl.data = [
        -1, -1, 0, 0.1,
        1, -1, 0, 0.1,
        -1, 1, 0, 0.1,
        -1, 1, 0, 0.1,
        1, -1, 0, 0.1,
        1, 1, 0, 0.1
    ];
    webgl.draw(gl.TRIANGLES);
    gl.uniform1i(webgl.modeUniformLoc, 0);
    webgl.data.length = 0;
}
webgl.draw = function (glType) {

    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(webgl.data), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.drawArrays(glType, 0, webgl.data.length / 4);
}

let fireworks = []
    , tick = 0
    , sins = []
    , coss = []
    , maxShardsParFirework = opts.baseShardsParFirework + opts.addedShardsParFirework
    , tau = 6.283185307179586476925286766559;

for (let i = 0; i < maxShardsParFirework; ++i) {
    sins[i] = Math.sin(tau * i / maxShardsParFirework);
    coss[i] = Math.cos(tau * i / maxShardsParFirework);
}

function Firework() {
    this.reset();
    this.shards = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < maxShardsParFirework; ++i)
        this.shards.push(new Shard(this));
}

Firework.prototype.reset = function () {

    let angle = -Math.PI / 2 + (Math.random() - .5) * opts.fireworkAngleSpan
        , vel = opts.baseFireworkVel * Math.random();

    this.mode = 0;
    this.vx = vel * Math.cos(angle);
    this.vy = vel * Math.sin(angle);

    this.x = Math.random() * w;
    this.y = Math.random() * h;

    this.hue = 0;
    let ph = this.hue
        , px = this.x
        , py = this.y;

    webgl.data.push(
        px, py, ph, opts.projectileAlpha * .2,
        this.x, this.y, this.hue, opts.projectileAlpha * .2);

}
Firework.prototype.step = function () {

    if (this.mode === 0) {
        this.mode = 1;
        this.shardAmount = opts.baseShardsParFirework + opts.addedShardsParFirework * Math.random() | 0;
        let baseAngle = Math.random() * tau
            , x = Math.cos(baseAngle)
            , y = Math.sin(baseAngle)
            , sin = sins[this.shardAmount]
            , cos = coss[this.shardAmount];

        for (let i = 0; i < this.shardAmount; ++i) {
            let vel = opts.baseShardVel + opts.addedShardVel * Math.random();
            this.shards[i].reset(x * vel, y * vel)
            let X = x;
            x = x * cos - y * sin;
            y = y * cos + X * sin;
        }
    }
    if (this.mode === 1) {

        this.ph = this.hue
        this.hue = 0;

        let allDead = true;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.shardAmount; ++i) {
            let shard = this.shards[i];
            if (!shard.dead) {
                shard.step();
                allDead = false;
            }
        }

        if (allDead)
            this.reset();
    }

}

function Shard(parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

Shard.prototype.reset = function (vx, vy) {
    this.x = this.parent.x;
    this.y = this.parent.y;
    this.vx = this.parent.vx * opts.shardFireworkVelMultiplier + vx;
    this.vy = this.parent.vy * opts.shardFireworkVelMultiplier + vy;
    this.starty = this.y;
    this.dead = false;
    this.tick = 1;
}
Shard.prototype.step = function () {

    this.tick += .05;

    let px = this.x
        , py = this.y;

    this.x += this.vx *= opts.xFriction;
    this.y += this.vy += opts.gravity;

    var proportion = 1 - (this.y - this.starty) / (h - this.starty);

    webgl.data.push(
        px, py, this.parent.ph, opts.projectileAlpha / this.tick,
        this.x, this.y, this.parent.hue, opts.projectileAlpha / this.tick);

    if (this.y > h)
        this.dead = true;
}

function anim() {

    window.requestAnimationFrame(anim);

    webgl.clear();

    ++tick;

    if (fireworks.length < opts.fireworks)
        fireworks.push(new Firework);

    fireworks.map(function (firework) {
        firework.step();
    });

    webgl.draw(gl.LINES);
}
anim();

window.addEventListener('resize', function () {

    w = c.width = window.innerWidth;
    h = c.height = window.innerHeight;

    gl.viewport(0, 0, w, h);
    gl.uniform2f(webgl.resUniformLoc, w, h);
});
```

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0;
}

#c {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"> </canvas>
```